# return an array inside chunk laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i wish you can help me.

I have the following code, outside of $export I want to return the value inside the $Paymentexport array, when I look at the browser console, it throws me the array as empty.

```
    $Paymentexport = [];    
    $export = Excel::filter('chunk')->load($path)->chunk(250, function ($results) use (&$Paymentexport){
      foreach($results as $payment){
        // code to import Excel in to DB
        $Paymentexport[] = [
          'hi' => 'hi'
          // I'm trying to push data to this array
        ];
      }
    });
    return $Paymentexport;
```

Comment: is $results not empty